# specify url in the multi selector invite friends

Tags: facebook

I have an application with button for invite friends with multi selector, but, the invite message redirect my friend to home of canvas url application, I can redirect the invite to specific sub url of my application?

Comment: You’ll have to do the redirecting once the user accepting a request arrives on your canvas – either a HTTP redirect, if you want to stay in the iframe, or JavaScript (top.location.href=…), if you want to get out. Where to redirect, you can decide on the request object’s details. (Provide the `data` parameter when creating the request, if necessary.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this below code to your website main page..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (top.location!= self.location)
{
top.location = self.location
}
</script>
```